# Why doesn't work the multer as a middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I the app.js there is a direct route `app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => { res.json({ message: 'pic uploaded' }); });`

When I make a post request to `/upload`, the image will be uploaded. However, when I use it like `app.use('/phones', phoneRoutes);` then the image won't be uploaded. Can you tell me where is the mistake? In both files everything is the same, but as I said, it works only in the app.js.

app.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const phoneRoutes = require('./routes/phoneRoute');
const multer = require('multer');

const cors = require('cors');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, './images');
  },

  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    console.log('file: ', file);
    cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

//initialize
const app = express();

//middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

//routes
app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'pic uploaded' });
});

app.use('/phones', phoneRoutes);

//connect to mongodb
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(process.env.PORT);
    console.log('Connected to mongodb: ', process.env.PORT);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

phoneRoutes.js:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const { createPhone } = require('../controllers/phoneController');
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, '../images');
  },

  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    console.log('file: ', file);
    cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'get phone: ' + req.params.id });
});

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: ' all Phones' });
});

router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'phone ' + req.params.id + ' is deleted' });
});

router.post('/', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'pic is uploaded' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What output do you receive? What is your URL?

Comment: I just use postman, the url is `http://localhost:4000/upload/`, and with that works, the output is `{
    "message": "pic uploaded"
}` , the second url is `http://localhost:4000/phones/` the output is `"pic is uploaded"` just as it should be, but the pic is not uploaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement

```js
cb(null, '../images');
```

contains a relative path, which is probably evaluated relative to the current working directory of the Node.js process. It is safer to make it relative to the directory containing the Javascript file `phoneRoutes.js`:

```js
cb(null, __dirname + '/../images');
```