# How to solve ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, crud, sqlconnection

I am writing a sign up/login page with node, using express, MySQL, dotenv, hbs e bcryptjs and nodemon. I run the code (which is below), but console returns me this error:

```
  code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
  errno: 1045,
  sqlMessage: "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)",
  sqlState: '28000',
  fatal: true
```

I am already running it on a admin user, and tried to give it permission by using SQL commands, but it didn't work.

It appears to be a error in my code or structure, not in SQL, since I got this error in two different computers, one having admin privileges and the other not[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQy0f.png)

```
app.js

const express = require('express');
const mysql = require("mysql");
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const app = express();
dotenv.config({ path: './.env'});

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE
});

db.connect((error) => {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error)
    } else {
        console.log("MySQL connected!")
    }
})
```

```
process.env

DATABASE = logindb
DATABASE_HOST = localhost
DATABASE_ROOT = root
DATABASE_PASSWORD =
```

What I tried with SQL:

```
create database logindb;

CREATE TABLE users (
id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
NAME VARCHAR(100),
email VARCHAR(100),
PASSWORD VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON users.* TO 'anajo'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '';

FLUSH privileges

SHOW GRANTS FOR 'anajo'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't work the multer as a middleware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72913013/why-doesnt-work-the-multer-as-a-middleware) `{path: './.env'}` is also evaluated relative to the current working directory of the Node.js process.

Comment: The answer didn't helped me, i changed the path, but i am getting the same error